# Showing $b_k(f)=\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin kt \ dt$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently studying for an exit exam on functional analysis. There's a question I'm currently working on which I'm weary on:

Let $X$ be the space of all continuous $2 \pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with inther product $$<f,g>=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t) \overline {g(t)}dt$$ and its associated norm. For each positive interger $k$ and each $f$ in $X$, let $b_k(f)=\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin kt \ dt$

A) Show that $b_k$ is a continuous linear functional on $X$

B) Find the norm of $b_k$ as a linear functional on $X$

C) Show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k(f)=0$ for each $f$ in $X$

**My Approach**

A) If I want to show $b_k$ is continuous, then it suffices to show $b_k$ is bounded$$\left |b_k(f) \right |= \left |\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin kt \ dt \right | \le ||f||\  |\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \left |\sin kt \ dt \right | $$ It's the "associated norm" portion that I have a question on. Do I have to use this norm to bound $\sin kt$: $$||f||_2= \left (\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \left |f(t) \right|^2 \right )^{1/2} dt$$

B) Once I have this bounded then $|b_k(f)|\le ||b||\  ||f||$

C) I'm thinking that when I bound $\sin kt$ above, I can just take $k$ to infinity and show that the limit is zero.

Please let me know if I'm on the right track. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Your first inequality is incorrect. There should be $|\sin(kt)|$ in the intergrand.

Comment: @John edited. I meant to put that thank u

Comment: As I remembered, the proof of (c) is not that elementary. I suggest you approximate $f$ by other simpler function (for example step function, or polynomial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain which norm you used to bound the inner product for A). You should appeal to Cauchy-Schwarz.

For B) note that $b_{k}\bigg(\frac{\sin(kt)}{\lvert\lvert\sin(kt)\rvert\rvert}_{L^{2}([-\pi,\pi])}\bigg)=\lvert\lvert\sin(kt)\rvert\rvert_{L^{2}([-\pi,\pi])}$ and think of part A. You have just bounded the operator norm you haven't found its value.

C is not as straight forward as simply bounding $\sin(kt)$. You need the increasing oscillations of $\sin(kt)$ to make the limit $0$. For C) first demonstrate this when $f$ is $C^{1}$. Then argue by density since we are working with a subset of $L^{2}([-\pi,\pi])$

Comment: That's why I'm confused I'm not sure myself which norm to use for part A? Is it even needed since you suggest Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: The functional $b_{k}$ is a functional from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In the space $X$ we use the norm $\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_{X}=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{2}(x)dx}$. So we seek a bound of the form $\lvert b_{k}(f)\rvert\le C\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_{X}$.

Comment: Ah ok so I had the correct norm. Thank you @user71352

Comment: You're welcome.